# ActionContext.getContext().getParameters() returns null during StrutsJUnit4TestCase

Tags: maven, struts2, junit, actioncontext, struts2-junit-plugin

I am running a JUnit test via maven where a struts action java method is being tested that makes the following call:

```
// Gets this from the "org.apache.struts2.util.TokenHelper" class in the struts2-core jar
String token = TokenHelper.getTokenName();
```

Here is the method in "TokenHelper.java":

```
/**
 * Gets the token name from the Parameters in the ServletActionContext
 *
 * @return the token name found in the params, or null if it could not be found
 */
public static String getTokenName() {

    Map params = ActionContext.getContext().getParameters();

    if (!params.containsKey(TOKEN_NAME_FIELD)) {
        LOG.warn("Could not find token name in params.");

        return null;
    }

    String[] tokenNames = (String[]) params.get(TOKEN_NAME_FIELD);
    String tokenName;

    if ((tokenNames == null) || (tokenNames.length < 1)) {
       LOG.warn("Got a null or empty token name.");

        return null;
    }

    tokenName = tokenNames[0];

    return tokenName;
}
```

The 1st line in this method is returning `null`:

```
Map params = ActionContext.getContext().getParameters();
```

The next LOC down, "params.containKey(...)" throws a NullPointerException because "params" is null.

When this action is called normally, this runs fine.  However, during the JUnit test, this Null Pointer occurs.

My test class looks like this:

```
@Anonymous
public class MNManageLocationActionTest extends StrutsJUnit4TestCase {

    private static MNManageLocationAction action;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        action = new MNManageLocationAction();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetActionMapping() {
        ActionMapping mapping = getActionMapping("/companylocation/FetchCountyListByZip.action");
        assertNotNull(mapping);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLoadStateList() throws JSONException {
        request.setParameter("Ryan", "Ryan");

        String result = action.loadStateList();

        assertEquals("Verify that the loadStateList() function completes without Exceptions.", 
              result, "success");
    }
}
```

The ActionContext.getContext() is at least no longer null after I switched to using StrutsJUnit4TestCase.

Any idea why .getParameters() is returning null?

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize parameters map by yourself inside your test method. Additionally if you want to get token name you need to put it in parameters map.

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put(TokenHelper.TOKEN_NAME_FIELD, 
                       new String[] { TokenHelper.DEFAULT_TOKEN_NAME });
ActionContext.getContext().setParameters(params);
```